# Not sure where to place fragment activity code

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and new to Android development (this is my first week coming from a windows background). I have an adapter that I'm attempting to add to a listview but I'm not sure where to place my code. I have multiple fragments being inflated from a flyout menu. I attempted placing the code in the fragment itself but this caused compilation errors, I also attempted placing the code in the main activity. Neither seemed to work correctly.

This is the code segment

```
var items = new String[] { "test", "test2" };
        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
        var listViewMeds = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.medicationListView);
        listViewMeds.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: Where do you currently have this code? What method in the Activity/Fragment have you put it under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will do this in the `OnCreateView` inside the fragment.

eg

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyLayoutId, container, false);

            ListAdapter = new MyAdapter(Activity, Items);
            return view;
}
```

Note that your fragment will need to be a `ListFragment` to be able to access the `ListAdapter` property.

Alternatively, if you don't have a `ListFragment` you can find your list view in the `OnCreateView`, eg.

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyLayoutId, container, false);

        var myListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.MyListViewId);
        myListView.ListAdapter = new MyAdapter(Activity, Items);
    }
```